# Bunch of zip binaries and a pckg_list

Tags: installation, package-management, zip

I got from one guy a directory with bunch of zip files (/binary/*), and a pckg_list file, with a structure like, for example, that:

```
Package : TIZEN-IDE
Version : 1.0.0
OS : windows
Build-host-os : linux
Maintainer : JongHwan Park <jonghwan2.park@samsung.com>
Attribute : meta
Install-dependency : assignmenttracing-eplugin, sdb, eventinjector-eplugin, telephony-eplugin, webapp-eplugin, document
Src-path : /source/meta-tizen-ide_1.0.0.tar.gz
Path : /binary/TIZEN-IDE_1.0.0_windows.zip
Origin : /home/sdk-package/dibs/unstable_public
SHA256 : e2ac88c0816bf1c966818e79f084413b97dce0fd3d8cd7f1086a10c6a46f67ce
Size : 545
Description : Install TIZEN IDE
```

Inside of zip files we can find *.manifest files and directories, sometimes with files, sometimes without.

So the question is:
How can i get those zips with binaries into my system? 
Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Hello Max, please edit your answer and add more detailed information about what the problem is.

Comment: Just did it. Hope it'll help.

Comment: not really. I don't have a clue on what you are actually trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

Tizen has their own installers to do already what are you trying to do https://developer.tizen.org/sdk

And this installer has two options: one where it downloads the file from the Internet and the other (as an Advanced buton in the initial stages of the installation)were you can manually specify a very big zip like probably for example `TIZEN-IDE_1.0.0_windows.zip`

What you have might be an internal version of the installer from Samsung, since Tizen is a opensource project you better try to install it from the above mentioned link, not to mention that if there is a release it will certainly appear online.